# How to limit visibility in OpenScales?

Tags: flex, openscales

I use flex and [OpenScale](http://openscales.org/) and I want to limit visibility just over Morocco using the coordinates, please how can I do that?!

```
    <os:Map id="fxmap" width="100%" height="100%" zoom="3" center="4.83212,45.75781">
    <os:Mapnik name="base"/>
    <os:DragHandler/>
    <os:ClickHandler/>
    <os:WheelHandler/>
    <os:PanZoom map="{map}" x="{fxmap.x+10}" y="{fxmap.y+10}"/>
</os:Map>
```

I can do that on the properties of the map ?

Comment: I've never heard about Open Scales.  This should be an interesting discussion.  http://openscales.org/

Comment: I can't get to openscales.org anymore. But there is a description of the project at https://www.openhub.net/p/openscales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'v found a solution not good but it's working and it's mine ^^

```
import org.openscales.geometry.basetypes.Pixel;
public function reCadreMap(e:MapEvent)
 {

//var x,y,x1,y1;
var maxLon =-1879357.2032504533;//left
var minLon=-015419.9442366438;//right

var maxLat=2440863.5691261655;//down
var minLat=4291633.447018889;//up
var border:Object=map.getLocationFromMapPx(new Pixel(map.width/2,map.height/2));
if(border["lon"]<maxLon){//left

    var lat= border["lat"]/100000;
    var lon=-15;

    map.moveTo(new Location(lon,lat),5,true,true);
}
else if(border["lon"]>minLon){//right
    var lat = (border["lat"]/100000)-5;
    var lon=-4;

    map.moveTo(new Location(lon,lat),4,true,true);
}
else if(border["lat"]>minLat){//up
    var lat = 33;
    var lon=(border["lon"]/100000);

    map.moveTo(new Location(lon,lat),5,true,true);
}
else if(border["lat"]<maxLat){//down
    var lat = 26;
    var lon=(border["lon"]/100000);

    map.moveTo(new Location(lon,lat),5,true,true);
}   

}
```

this exemple is for who want to limit visibility, and i'm attending any reaction from you !